# What was Hans Gruber's plan in Die Hard?

Tags: plot-explanation, die-hard

In *Die Hard*, at some point, Hans Gruber reveals a part of his plan to John McClane:

> When you steal six hundred dollars,
>                    you can disappear...but when you
>                    steal six hundred million, they will
>                    find you...unless you play dead.
>   <sub>[Die Hard](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Die-Hard.html)</sub>

It is unclear to me how Hans is planning to accomplish that. What follows next seems to imply to me that he plans to use McClane for that:

> Which happens to be your next role...
>                    drop your gun, please.
>   <sub>ibid</sub>

But how did he plan to do that originally? Without McClane causing a ruckus, it is likely that cops wouldn't have shown up to cut of the power and there would have been no uninvited guest who couldn't be identified afterwards.

So what exactly was Hans' plan before McClane arrived?

Comment: Didn’t Gruber say something like “it only means, it all starts a bit earlier” when McClane gets the attention of the police?

Comment: @Holger this? "The police are irrelevant.  We've                    
                 waiting for the FBI.  Until they                     
                 arrive, we can't finish out work.
                 Meanwhile, let this fool waste time
                 for the police."

Comment: Perhaps. I’ll rewatch it. It’s the right time for rewatching it anyway ;-)

Comment: The Nakatomi Corporation has plans, the cops have plans, McClane’s got plans. Does Gruber really look like a guy with a plan? You know what he is? He’s a dog chasing cars. He wouldn’t know what to do with $640 million in bearer bonds if he caught them.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite well, he does have a taste for good suits, so maybe he is planning on buying some of those :P

Comment: Hans' quote isn't quite right here... it should be "Well, when you steal $600, you can just disappear. When you steal 600 million, they will find you, unless they think you're already dead." -[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095016/quotes)

Comment: "Which happens to be your next role" just means "I'm going to kill you." McClane isn't part of his plan.

Comment: @ArrowCase hence the question, **what was?**

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Let's go through the plan of Hans Gruber without the interference from John McClane.

1. Infiltrate Nakatomi Tower with his goons and take the Christmas party-goers hostage.
2. Get the vault password from Takagi (or kill him, doesn’t really matter).
3. Have Theo hack most of the vault locks.
4. Call the police and pretend to be terrorists.
5. Annihilate the SWAT team with rocket launchers.
6. Wait until FBI shows up and cuts the power to the building, thus unlocking the last lock.
7. Steal $640 million in bearer bonds.
8. Blow up all the hostages on the roof with C4 when the FBI gunship shows up and escape in the confusion.

([Source](https://tropeanddagger.com/2015/05/15/hans-grubers-plan-the-best-villainous-plan-in-movies/))

Hans was, as it seems so, great at planning. He planned this to every detail. He knew that Takagi won't give him the password, but it really didn't matter because Theo was going to hack it anyway. They planned to call themselves terrorists so FBI can show up and cut the power which eventually open the last lock.

He knew functioning of FBI and police. You can see that he identifies both FBI agents.

> It is unclear to me how Hans is planning to accomplish that.

It is not really explained in the movie, but it is not hard to assume.

Hans was going to blow up the terrace with C4, so FBI and police get diverted and he can escape. He and his gang weren't going to show themselves to the police. They had planned escaping in the ambulance which Theo gets ready near the end. So, if they'd have blew up the terrace with hostages and didn't reveal themselves, everybody would assume that they also died in the blast.

> Without McClane causing a ruckus, it is likely that cops wouldn't have shown up to cut of the power and there would have been no uninvited guest who couldn't be identified afterwards.

They were going to call the police anyway even if McClane doesn't show up. Also note that their plan wasn't altered that much even when McClane showed up. Things only went bad when McClane got their detonators and explosives.

Comment: It's worth noting that they were probably planning on escaping in the ambulance that Theo is seen getting ready towards the end.

Comment: It's been a long time since I watched this movie, so I don't remember the ambulance, but thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Yeah, Theo preps the ambulance and then the limo driver, Argyle, who is chilling/trapped in the garage rams it with the limo to disable and then punches Theo unconscious. Also remember that one of the first people John kills has the detonators for the C4, which means for the first half of the siege they *must* capture or kill John to get the detonators back. Hans mentions this several times, because the detonators are crucial to the plan.

Comment: That sounds like a terrible plan. If they have rocket launchers and C4, why didn't they just cut the power to the building themselves? They could've been in & out before the FBI even knew what happened. They may not even have had to take hostages.

Comment: @Chloe Good luck finding all the places where power goes, and the redundant supplies to the vault.  Although AFAIK vaults generally shut down hard when the power goes out.

Comment: @Graham While true that something like a vault would typically employ a fail-secure mechanism over a fail-safe one, this vault's final lock was one that required power to operate ("electromagnetic seal"). Apparently it had no internal redundant power bank to maintain the seal in the event of power loss.

Comment: +1 to Chloe's comment, it probably would have been easier to just set an explosion(s) underground and cut off power for the whole area, then disappear in the ambulance, or just walk away in the dark before anyone showed up. Even the hostages & vault code seem completely  unnecessary. The "unless you play dead" wouldn't matter if you're unknown, and the bearer bonds are either untraceable or they'll know you're alive when you use them anyway.

Comment: @Graham "Good luck finding all the power points" because finding the power leads is harder than understanding a building, a top tier safe, cops, FBI, the hostages, having an ambulance ready, etc? I've never considered the alternatives but... how is a "diabolical" plan like unfolded not 10x more complicated than bribing/threatening the building designer?

Comment: @chloe they didn't do it themselves because "When you steal 600 million, they will find you, unless they think you're already dead." If not for the elaborate plan and terrorist act it will be clear the $600 million in bonds was the goal from the get go. The investigation will start there under the immediate premise the perpetrators are alive with an active manhunt, and it will be much harder to get away. cont...

Comment: With the elaborate plan, "we'll blow the roof, they'll spend a month sifting through rubble, and by the time they figure out what went wrong, we'll be sitting on a beach, earning twenty percent." the investigation begins as a terrorist plot linked to some people Hans read about in Time magazine under the presumption the perpetrators are dead. By the time the bonds are missed (they might even be assumed destroyed). Hans et. al are safely out of the country and the whole situation is still linked to the people Hans read about in Time magazine.

Comment: @WernerCD well, to bribe the building designer you might first have to learn his language, which could in some instances [be a bit unpleasant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Do-wDPoC6GM)...

Comment: @Chloe: the power wasn’t simply cut, even if we’re used to call it that way. The field worker under the FBI agent’s pressure does neither, cut a cable nor turn a switch. He makes a *phone call*. So the power was willingly disabled by the supplier’s control center on FBI’s command, turning off all redundant supplies and the alarms as well, something you can’t achieve by just destroying some cables.

Comment: @WernerCD: what does bribing/threatening the building designer help you when all you find out, is, that the cables are running through the supporting structures of the building, requiring you to destroy the entire building when trying to forcefully cut them? That’s the whole plot point that the building has been carefully crafted to make such a raw attempt impossible. It requires the help of the power plant, something outside the architect’s control…

Comment: @Holger Yes, arguably Rick Ducommun’s finest on-screen moment of his short career was radioing (it wasn’t a phone call) the central office and asking, “So listen, would it be possible for you turn off, ah, grid 212?” Regarding the larger question of cutting the power, we are reminded several times that “the circuits cannot be cut locally”. So the vault was designed to not be openable unless an entire city grid went down. Whether that’s believable or not, that’s the plot point in the movie.

Comment: @Todd Wilcox: I didn’t meant “phone call” literally. Though, if the movie was shot today, he very likely used a cell phone. It’s hard to believe that such an elaborated vault design doesn’t include a backup battery, but anyway, it’s a good action movie…

Answer (score 5):

As far as the initial timeline about the FBI and the power being shut off  that has been covered in other answers but I always assumed that the escape was also planned as such...

- They requested the helicopter to make it appear that this is how they
  were going to escape to the airport with hostages via the roof.
- They had the C4 planted on the roof to blow it up and make it appear
  that the police had caused the explosion during this faux escape.
- Meanwhile they would be waiting in the ambulance ready to escape
  disguised as first-responders responding to the massive casualties
  caused by the explosion.

If all had gone according to plan, everyone would have thought that they had all died at the hands of the FBI and the bonds had been destroyed in the explosion.

Answer (score 3):

A large building like the Nakatomi Tower would have multiple power sources, and even the city worker wasn't able to cut all of the power locally; it had to be shut down from the Power Station downtown. The power infrastructure was too complex for Hans to defeat - but very simple for the FBI to accomplish with the forced flip of a switch as they followed the "Universal Terrorist Playbook": The circuits that cannot be cut are cut automatically in response to a terrorist incident.